# RxSwift: Combine two network request to return one value

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, google-places-autocomplete

I have two network requests that I would like to combine the results in one array of Object.

```
enum ResultType<T> {
  case success(T)
  case failure(Error)
}

static func requestPlaceSearch(query: String) -> Observable<ResultType<SearchResult>> {
    let urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json"
    let params = ["input": query, "types": "geocode",
                "key": "key"]
    return placeRequest(url: urlString, params: params)
}

static func requestPlace(with placeId: String) -> Observable<ResultType<Place>> {
    let params = ["placeid": placeId, "key": "key"]
    let urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json"
    return placeRequest(url: urlString, params: params)
}
```

`requestPlaceSearch` returns and observable of `SearchResult`
I want to loop through `SearchResult.predictions`, get the id of each prediction make a request to `requestPlace` get the `Place` an append to array of `Places`

I want my final array to be

```
let places = Observable<[Place]>
```

or

```
let places = [Place]()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to give you the answer, but I'm going to draw it out by explaining how I came up with the answer. Hopefully, you can emulate the process and be able to come up with the answer yourself in the next attempt.

Start with:

```
let foo = requestPlaceSearch(query: "")
```

And look at `foo`'s type which is: `Observable<ResultType<SearchResult>>`. Okay from there we need to extract the search result from the result type. So...

```
let foo = requestPlaceSearch(query: "")
    .map { (result: ResultType<SearchResult>) -> SearchResult? in
        if case let .success(search) = result {
            return search
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Now what is `foo`'s type? `Observable<SearchResult?>`. So lets filter out the optionals.

```
let foo = requestPlaceSearch(query: "")
    .map { (result: ResultType<SearchResult>) -> SearchResult? in
        if case let .success(search) = result {
            return search
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    .filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
```

Now `foo` is of type: `Observable<SearchResult>` So we can pull out the `predictions`.

```
let foo = requestPlaceSearch(query: "")
    .map { (result: ResultType<SearchResult>) -> SearchResult? in
        if case let .success(search) = result {
            return search
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    .filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
    .map { $0.predictions }
```

We are going to need that function to extract the success object again so let's move that into a separate function:

```
func extractSuccess<T>(_ result: ResultType<T>) -> T? {
    if case let .success(search) = result {
        return search
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that `predictions` are just strings. You might have to extract the string IDs from it. So now foo is of type `Observable<[String]>`. Now that we have the ids we can call the other endpoint.

```
let foo = requestPlaceSearch(query: "")
    .map(extractSuccess)
    .filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
    .map { $0.predictions }
    .map { $0.map(requestPlace) }
```

Now `foo` is of type `Observable<[Observable<ResultType<Place>>]>`. Next let's turn the [Observable] into a Observable<[T]>.

```
let foo = requestPlaceSearch(query: "")
    .map(extractSuccess)
    .filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
    .map { $0.predictions }
    .map { Observable.combineLatest($0.map(requestPlace)) }
```

Which makes foo a `Observable<Observable<[ResultType<Place>]>>`. An Observable> can be flattened out pretty easy.

```
let foo = requestPlaceSearch(query: "")
    .map(extractSuccess)
    .filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
    .map { $0.predictions }
    .flatMap { Observable.combineLatest($0.map(requestPlace)) }
```

That turns foo into an `Observable<[ResultType<Place>]>`

```
let foo = requestPlaceSearch(query: "")
    .map(extractSuccess)
    .filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
    .map { $0.predictions }
    .flatMap { Observable.combineLatest($0.map {
        requestPlace(with: $0)
            .map(extractSuccess)
            .filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
        })
    }
```

The part I added in the above is the same as the last one that returns a result type. Also, at this point `foo` is of type `Observable<[Place]>` and we're done.

Note that this code doesn't deal with any of the failure results. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for saving a life, I have refactored the final output in my code to be an observable of<Result> where result is a struct of `placeName: String` and `places: [Place]`